# Where is the registry location for IE settings?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, windows-registry

Where is the setting (registry I'm assuming) that holds this Advanced setting for Internet Explorer 8:

"Disable script debugging (Internete Explorer)"

I keep needing to uncheck when debugging Javascript in VS. I think my companies logon script flips it on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
```

Modify **Disable Script Debugger** and set it to **no** to enable debugging.

If the value is not there, create it as a string value (REG_SZ) with the name and value above.

In case of IE 9 and above,the above is not enough to make it work. Additionally, check for the key "DisableScriptDebuggerIE" in the same place as above and set it to no as well.

Comment: @Tarun I approved your edit, but note the question was for IE8. If you're on a different version of IE or a newer version of windows, please note that in the edit.